# WinMerge select "Tools" -> "Generate Report" missing

Tags: select, report, winmerge

I used to have nice HTML reporting in WinMerge by selecting "Tools" -> "Generate Report".  Now that feature is missing.  Does anyone have a link to that plugin?  I've been scouring the prior versions in 7zip format to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the "Generate Report" feature was there all along.  My mistake was in assuming that the menu item would be visible when the application first opened.  Once I did a file compare, the  "Tools" -> "Generate Report" option appeared.  Sorry for the confusion.  (Great feature for archiving code reviews BTW.)